# Image cycle loading out of place

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, caroufredsel

When loading a page with the CarouFredSel image cycle it is always shifted a little to the right until I either go to the next image or reload the page, same issue happens after a hard refresh.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".photos").carouFredSel({
    width: "100%",
    height: "465px",
    items: {
        visible: 1,
        width: "variable",
        height: "465px"
    },
    scroll: {
        fx: "none",
        duration: 1
    },
    auto: 50000,
    prev: {
        button: ".prev",
        key: "left"
    },
    next: {
        button: ".next",
        key: "right"
    },
    pagination: {
        container: ".pagination",
        keys: true
    },
    swipe: true,
    mousewheel: true
})
});
```

I've tried posting this several times before and no one has given me any info yet and it's really holding me up, and help would be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think there is something wrong in that plugin. On page load it sets a `left` style on your `.photos` container. When you click on the image and it all gets nicely aligned in the middle, the `left` changes.

Comment: is there a way to catch this before it loads and set it to the correct property?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a problem with your configuration of CarouFredSel.  I made a jsfiddle of your code and it works fine.(http://jsfiddle.net/YdAee/).  I'm going to guess it has something to do with your masonry code, but that's just a guess because that is throwing an error.  Look at this code:

```
///////MASONRY/////
if (randomComplete == true) {
    $('#boxes').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.box'
    });
}
```

randomComplete is defined out of scope.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me! Just fixed the randomComplete issue, was using the `var` in different `$(window).load` sections. The only error I'm seeing now is being caused by an ad blocking plugin

Comment: I'd try disabling and enabling any other js that messes with layout (like masonry) to see if there is a conflict.  Do you see anything I left out in  my fiddle?  Because it works fine there.  I did use jQuery 1.8.3, and I think you're using 1.8.1, but all the other includes I'm pulling from your site.

Comment: just changed it to have 1.8.3 linked in with no javascript related code except the required carouFredSel stuff. still no luck :/

Comment: I just put it in a `$(window).load` instead and now it loads in a stack on the left side of the page before jumping to the right place automatically. Is there a way I can get this to load faster or just not have it visible until its done loading?